# How to permanently disable my trackpad?

Tags: trackpad

I want to permanently disable my trackpad on my Dell Inspiron running Ubuntu 13.10. I read some threads in this forum and tried to make a BIOS setting change.  Nothing worked.  Whenever my bluetooth mouse took a nap the trackpad came back on.  Finally I moved the `50-synaptics.conf` file out of the `/user/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/` directory and my problem is solved.

Is there another alternative?

It sure would be nice for the blue Fn-trackpad key to work.  It would obviously be better if X did not enable the trackpad without my request just because my bluetooth mouse is trying to save batteries.

Comment: The way you did it would probably be the best way..

Answer (score 2):

Run the following command in a terminal:

```
xinput list
```

You will get an output that looks like this:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Laptop_Integrated_Webcam_1.3M             id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Dell WMI hotkeys                          id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

It displays all the input devices connected. Note that they all have an id. 
Since 12 is the id for my touchpad, running the following command will disable it.

```
xinput set-prop 12 "Device Enabled" 0
```